# creating multiple editable ggplots in powerpoint

Tags: r, loops, powerpoint

I am trying to create a way to take a list of ggplots and turn them into a powerpoint with each slide being an editable ggplot from the list. Below I provided the code I have and explained in the notes where the issue occurs aka during the loop. It seems like it is overriding itself when looping.

````
```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
```
#create example data 
```
df <- data.frame(country = c(rep('USA',20), rep('Canada',20), rep('Mexico',20)),

                 wave = c(1:20, 1:20, 1:20),

                 par = c(1:20 + 5*runif(20), 21:40 + 10*runif(20), 1:20 + 15*runif(20)))

 

countries <- unique(df$country)

 ```

#make list of plots 
```
plot_list <- list()

i <- 1

 

for (c in countries){

  pl <- ggplot(data = df %>% filter(country == c)) +

    geom_point(aes(wave, par), size = 3, color = 'red') +

    labs(title = as.character(c), x = 'wave', y = 'value') +

    theme_bw(base_size = 16)

 

  plot_list[[i]] <- pl

  i <- i + 1

}

#plot_list is the list of plots 
plot_list

 

#convert list of plots into editable vector graphic objects

myplots <-  dml(ggobj = plot_list

                ,bg = "white"

                ,pointsize = 12

                ,editable = TRUE)
 

### now create loop ---- this is were I get issues. it seems like the plots are just overriding one another during the loop and not creating a new slide

{

  for(plot in 1:length(plot_list)) {

    doc <- read_pptx()

    doc <- add_slide(doc, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")

    doc <- ph_with(doc, plot_list[[plot]], location = ph_location_fullsize())

    fileout <- "vectorGraphics.pptx"

    print(doc, target = fileout)

  }

}

 ```
````

Comment: Take `read_pptx()` and `print(doc, ...)` out of the loop (otherwise you re-initialize `doc` every loop cycle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest to use `lapply` to create your list of plots. Second, to convert your plots to `dml` objects you have to loop over the list of plots. Finally, if you want one pptx with each plot on a separate slide, create and export the pptx outside of the `for` loop:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

plot_list <- df |>
  split(~country) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    ggplot(x) +
      geom_point(aes(wave, par), size = 3, color = "red") +
      labs(title = unique(x$country), x = "wave", y = "value") +
      theme_bw(base_size = 16)
  })

plot_list_dml <- lapply(
  plot_list, \(x)
  dml(
    ggobj = x,
    bg = "white",
    pointsize = 12,
    editable = TRUE
  )
)

doc <- read_pptx()
for (plot in plot_list_dml) {
  doc <- add_slide(doc, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")

  doc <- ph_with(doc, plot, location = ph_location_fullsize())
}

fileout <- "vectorGraphics.pptx"

print(doc, target = fileout)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the loop:

```
doc <- read_pptx()
for(plot in 1:length(plot_list)) {
  doc <- add_slide(doc, "Title and Content", "Office Theme")
  doc <- ph_with(doc, plot_list[[plot]], location = ph_location_fullsize())
}
fileout <- "vectorGraphics.pptx"
print(doc, target = fileout)
```

Per your deleted comment: Just move some lines outside the loop.